# Implicit conversion at compile time

Tags: c#, .net

We know that a `double` literal value won't be implicitly converted to `float` due to data loss at compile time:

[image]

We also know that `int` won't be implicitly converted to `byte` as well, but in this case, taking into account the literal is `int`, it works:

[image]

Would you mind explaining me what's the process happening there and how it works under the hood?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A literal integer is a *constant*, it will *never change*. The compiler can therefore reason out at *compile time* if the implicit conversion is safe and if it is, its nice enough to do it for you.

Thats also the reason why `byte i = 300;` will fail at compile time.

The same can’t be said when the conversion is of a non constant value; a *variable*. There is no way the compiler can know what value `i` will be so the implicit conversion is unsafe and disallowed.

Concerning why this behavior seems off with floats and doubles (see comments): The reason is that there *is* a float literal in the language, so if you want a float literal, *use a float literal*. There is no byte or short literal so the compiler helps you out

Also, fitting a valid `int` into a `byte` implies no loss of data/precision; the bits are the same, you are simply truncating 0 bits on the high end. The same can't be said when you convert a `double` into a `float`. The representation of any given number as a single or double precision floating point number are radically different and there is an inherent loss of precision. It stands to reason that the language design decisions differ between both scenarios as they are different alltogether.

Comment: Good answer, but for me it seems like it still doesn't cover the double-to-float case. `4.2` **is** a constant, but it's not working for it this way

Comment: If you want to declare a `float` constand instead of a `double` constant you can postfix it with an f like `4.2f`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev `4.2` is a **double**-constant. `4.2f` is a **float**-constant. 99 is a **byte**-constant. However byte is implicityle convertible to int, making `int i = 99` work.

Comment: Yes, I know, thank you :) I just guessed that this information should become a part of the answer

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev The reason is that there is a float literal in the language, so if you want a float literal, write one. There is no byte or short literal so the compiler helps you out.

Comment: @InBetween: i doubt it's the lack of the byte literal but that there is no implicit conversion from double to float.

Comment: The same people who decided to allow implicit conversions of compile time constants to smaller integers *could* also have provided byte and short literals. In both cases, they were language design decisions, and it does seem slightly odd that they went one way with the integral types and a different way with floating point.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The design decisions are different because the problem is different. Casting down to a byte is always safe if the number is in range and there is no loss of precision or information. That is not true when converting from double to float. It stands to reason that the former be implicit when it’s proven to be safe and the latter should be always explicit because it’s never safe; floats and doubles are radically different things.